# Windows 7 offers updates from year 2013

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have an old laptop with Windows 7 Home and I run always all suggested updates.

Yesterday I was installing all pending updates.
I check always the release date of each update because I don't want to install a fresh released update [in case there is a problem and Microsoft withdraws it from the update list] and I noticed in the update list 2 updates from year 2013!

**My question:**
How can this be? According to the below screen shots the updates were almost 5 years old. All updates have been installed successfully.

[image]

[image]

---

- I didn't reset the Windows Update
- The exported [Update History](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=92759843418587210936)

Comment: Did you recently "reset" Windows Update in attempt to resolve a problem by chance?

Comment: Sometimes when you add software that uses for example C++, it will want to patch the older C++ since it is now in use or installed an unpatched version when installing the software.

Comment: @Moab OK, indeed I installed yesterday a program. This could be but when you check my screenshot you see that the _Microsoft Security Essentials_ have been updated which have as date 2013-11-26.

Comment: @AlBundy - What is the last cumulative update you installed?  You should edit your question to include this vital information.

Comment: I didn't want to know when you installed a patch, I wanted to know which patch you installed, knowing you installed a patch on that date does not answer my question.

Comment: @Ramhound I appreciate your help but I am not sure if I understand what you want to see. I edited the question and added a link to an exported of the Windows Update History - does it help?

Comment: @AlBundy - I want to know which specific cumulative update you installed on 2018-04-15.  I am trying to determine if you installed a recent cumulative update, an extremely old cumulative update, or something else entirely.  *I just need the patch number*